# status of client is open not registered

Tags: symmetricds

Hello I am working on android project with sqlite database.
I am using Symmetricds pro for the replication between client and server.
status is open but not registered at server side and there is no option to allow registration.
May I know why?
thanks in advance srikanthg

Answer (score 1):

Add to the central server's engine properties config file:

```
auto.registration=true
auto.reload=true
```

Comment: have you restarted both central and client instance?

Comment: i am unable to find log files... at client

Comment: I am working on android project..May I know where can I find log file

Comment: I don't know, but without the logs it's going to be very hard debugging the synchronization